# Iphone mapKit ,Large Images & Large data causing memory warnings & crashes

Tags: iphone, memory-management, mapkit, large-data

I am working on an app and now I am stucked. I think I this is due to lack of earlier planning. Actually I earlier didnt know that I will be getting so much of data in my app and thats why now at the final stages of my app , I am getting memory warnings.

Basically I am using a MapKit and getting the data from my server , store them in arrays and use that data to display something on map, thats a huge amount of data which I am getting from server .

In some other view , I am downloading large images from server and again some large data to display on image and using arrays to store that data.

I have checked there are no leaks in the app. But the problem is that when I zoom in and out of the map and go back and forth and then again zoom in and out of the map, I recieve memory warnings, my previous views are unloaded. The problem is that previous views also get their data from server and since my app target users will be 3g users and not WIFI , it will be very difficult if again and again they go back and whole data again gets downloaded from server.

SO basically my problem is that how to store large data? Is there a way to reduce the memory usage of MapKit or is it a known bug? Please help me. its very urgent . I m stucked in it from long and not able to get any solution

Comment: The solution provided by jasamer is valid, but basically I want to know why the memory warnings are coming even there are no leaks, and these memory warnings doesn't come when I don't zoom in or out of the map or images, why this all is causing me a great problem when I am going totally with the apple provided methods like NSXMLParser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) and setup a ASIDownloadCache. This way when a controller is forced to unload the data and has to re-download it, the data is already locally available.

Comment: I am using Apple's NSXMLParser and switching to some other parsing method , would be equal to starting from scratch , as I said my app is on final stage and my whole app gets the data from my server .. Please I hope there is some other solution too with you or someone else, please dont tell me there is no other solution, please help me guys , anyways thanks for ur help

Comment: No, it wouldn't be like starting from scratch... you just use NSXMLParsers' initWithData: method instead of initWithURL:, and use the ASIHTTP-stuff to download the data. The other options would be more work - like saving the images manually and only load them when required, or use CoreData for your data storing needs.